# Blazor: Inherited component with no content displays as empty

Tags: blazor

I saw many examples of inherited components. They all look like:

```
Base.razor:
@code{
    //some code here.
}

Inherited.razor:
@inherits Base
<div>
    //some content here
</div>
```

Now what I'm doing is just on the other side:

```
Base.razor:
<div>
    //some content here
</div>

Inherited.razor:
@inherits Base

@code{
    //some code here, initializing parameters, override some methods.
}
```

But if I use

```
<Inherited></Inherited>
```

to render it, it's empty. What shall I do then? Any help will be appreciated.

More real code here:

Base(CrudIndex2.razor):

```
@typeparam TItem where TItem : class, LibInterfaceBase.IIdable, new()

@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<GlobalRes> GlobalLocalizer

@if (!Loaded)
{
    <MudProgressCircular Color="Color.Primary" Indeterminate="true"/>
}
else
{
    <MudTable>...</MudTable>
}
```

Inherited:

```
@page "/AdaPPM/MeasureItemDefinitions/Index"
@inherits CrudIndex2<LibAdaMetrics.DataRecords.MeasureItemDefinition>

@code
{
//    int CurrentUser = await _authenticationManager.CurrentUser();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        base.InitBase(
            typeof(CreateOrEditMeasureItemDefinitionDialog),
            AdaHubMeasureItemDefinitions.Instance);

        CurrentUser = await _authenticationManager.CurrentUser();
        CanCreate = (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(CurrentUser, Permissions.MeasurementBaselines.Create)).Succeeded;
        CanEdit = (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(CurrentUser, Permissions.MeasurementBaselines.Edit)).Succeeded;
        CanDelete = (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(CurrentUser, Permissions.MeasurementBaselines.Delete)).Succeeded;

        await ResetAsync();
        Loaded = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Inherited.razor` provides no content, and the content of the base class will  *not* be rendered.

This specific case can be fixed by putting your derived class in a plain cs file:

**Inherited.cs**

```
public class Inherited : CrudIndex2
{
  ...
}
```

But a more common pattern is to turn that around: `Base.cs` and `Inherited.razor`

It will work as long as only 1 class is from a .razor file.

Comment: Both your suggestions are workarounds that work in some cases, but if you look at the generated razor.g.cs  code, the solution is pretty straitforward - just call `base.BuildRenderTree(__builder)` at the right place.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Yes that must be a reason that people do not do that. I will try to reverse the logic.

Comment: @Liero Yes, that certainly works. But the `__` in `__builder` is a strong hint that you shouldn't be doing that as a common practice.  The better solution would be using composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @HH: Point taken. Regarding composition, be careful about possible negative performance effect when passing parameters.

Comment: Yes, the best solution would depend very much on circumstances. I should have said "_A_ better solution".

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

add this to your Inherited.razor

```
@inherits Base
@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}
@code{
    //some code here, initializing parameters, override some methods.
}
```

#### Explanation:

a razor compiler generates `override BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) { ... }` method with compiled markup of the component. In your case, there is none. You just need to call the base method.

#### Extra tip:

If there isn't any razor markup, just use plain old C# class Inherited.cs (or you might use Inherited.razor.cs if you whish).

Comment: as @HH pointed out, `__` in `__builder` is a strong hint that you shouldn't be doing that as a common practice. That's a valid point that should be taken into consideration

Comment: I tried this before and got an error: __builder cannot be resolved. So where comes this __builder?